# Intent is not working, when the state of a button is checked

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to build a flight ticket booking app.
Here I have two options either user selects one-way or round-way(both sides). When a user selects one-way I need to go to the next screen where all one-way flight details will be shown. Other-wise if a user selects round-way then I will show the details of the round trip to the user.

But if I select one-way(Button) and check it's Pressed state it shows False, So I am unable to navigate the user to the next screen and the same flaw is happening for the round-way.

> MainActivity

```
    private void searchClickHandeler(){

        //Set Onclick Listener
        b_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
*when One way is pressed it is suppose to go to the One way Suggestion Activity*

            if (b_oneway.isPressed()){
                Toast.makeText(FlightActivity.this,"Oneway Button is pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                Intent oneway = new Intent(FlightActivity.this,FlightSuggestionActivity.class);

                startActivity(oneway);

            } else if (b_returnway.isPressed()){
                Toast.makeText(FlightActivity.this,"RoundTrip Button is pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent returnway = new Intent(FlightActivity.this,FlightRoundTripSuggestionActivity.class);

                startActivity(returnway);

            }
           }

        });
        }
```

Comment: what is **`b_oneway.isPressed()`** share your whole activity code with question

Comment: what view is b_oneway?

Comment: mention b_oneway, b_returnway intializations

Comment: add some more code and be clear of what you ask

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FlightSuggestionActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```